# Unknown type: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am trying to debug a Java application that I am writing. In the application I am using the `StringUtils` class. I currently have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which is being thrown on the line where I am calling a method on the `StringUtils` class. However, when I try to evaluate the portion of code which uses StringUtils, I get the following popup in NetBeans:

> Unknown type: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

I have added the relevant JAR file to my classpath and I am importing the class correctly. Even  evaluating simple expressions using `StringUtils`methods cause this message to be shown. If I evaluate expressions that use methods from classes in the java.* package, this seems to go OK.

Here is a sample of the code I have written:

```
String[] numbersArray;
boolean negativeNumberFound = false;
String message = "Negatives not allowed ";
if (numbers.contains("//")) {
    String delimeters = numbers.substring(2, StringUtils.lastIndexOf("]", numbers, 2)).replaceAll("[|]", "");
    numbersArray = numbers.split(String.valueOf(numbers.charAt(2)));
} else {
    numbersArray = numbers.split(",|\\n|:|_");
}
```

I saw [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic31390.html) post on the NetBeans forums where the user also seemed to have the same issue but it looks like the issue never got resolved at the time. Perhaps a newer version (I am using 8.0.2) may have resolved this somehow?